# Render element after form is submitted

Tags: 8, forms

I would like to show a "Thank you"-overlay after my contact form is submitted. I already tried this, but this seems to fire one step too early:

```
function my_theme_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['isSubmitted'] = true;
}

{% if form.isSubmitted %}
    <div class="overlay">Thank you!</div>
{% endif %}
```

I could probably rewrite this whole thing into ajax, but a simple solution is much preferred.

Comment: Yes, Ajaxify the submit.

Comment: If Ajax and Javascript is not an option you can rebuild the form and display the message instead of form elements. Like a multistep form, only that the last form page doesn't contain a form anymore. A simple solution, though, would be to set a message which will be displayed on the next page after the form is submitted, which is by default the same empty form.